# how to populated dropdown with multiple path using javascript html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on Excel Web Add-Ins project which is I need to make a connection with several shared folder path. When the user choose path in the dropdown, then it automatically fetch the data and open it in the excel sheet. I'm using JavaScript and HTML in Visual Studio.

So here is my HTML code:

```
<td><label class="ms-Label is-required ms-font-l">Path : </label></td>
<td>
    <select class="ms-Dropdown-item--selected is-required" id="path">
        <option href="\\myservername.com\Fin1\ ">Server 1</option>
        <option href="\\myservername.com\Fin2\ ">Server 2</option>
        <option href="\\myservername.com\Fin3\ ">Server 3</option>
</select>
 </td>

<script>
   document.getElementById('path').onchange = function (ctx) {
       window.location.href = this.children[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('href');
   } </script>
```

Each option connect with different server path. 
I try using ***window.location.href*** but when I choose the server path, the output replacing my form. 
I want it display the output on the excel worksheet not replacing my form.

Comment: Hi Syahira, Welcome to stack overflow. Can you share your work with us?

Comment: Hello Welcome to StackOverflow, This question does not provide enough information about the problem. Always try to provide some information related to what you tried so far with some of your code. Help people to help you. also have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi @ZeeshanAdil I'm sorry for not providing enough information so I make some change to my post. Hope you can help.

Comment: Are you tried target="_blank" attribute? Used window.open(path,'_blank');

Comment: If you are using jQuery then the syntax like this var path = $(this). Attr('href'). Attr('path', '_blank');

Comment: I try using  target="_blank" attribute but it display in new window.. What I need is the output display in excel Worksheet.

Comment: In short you want to display data in Excel within Browser in that scenario you need plugin https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx this link may help you